# How to build LLVM/Clang isolated from the host system?

Tags: cross-compilation, lfs, llvm, clang

I'm looking for something like the Linux From Scratch process for GCC, but for LLVM/Clang.

Linux From Scratch builds an isolated GCC/binutils toolchain, and because of the rather monolithic nature, `the process is relatively simple.

But how would one do the same with LLVM/Clang/compiler_rt/libcxx/libcxxabi/lld etc? How do I build it totally isolated from the host, from scratch?

I've read the documentation for the tools, and it's been unhelpful. As far as I can tell, none of them fully document the build, or even their CMake options, let alone the bootstrapping process.

And none of them document their inter-dependencies, they all just link to LLVMs?